# Разница значения полей в таблице(БД)

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql, plsql-developer

Из базы получается таблица следующего вида:

```
Event  |   Date
-----------------------------
IN     |  01.12.2015 13:00
OUT    |  01.12.2015 13:15
IN     |  01.12.2015 16:00
OUT    |  01.12.2015 19:45
IN     |  02.12.2015 14:00
OUT    |  02.12.2015 16:00
```

Теперь необходимо вычислить сумму всех разниц во времени между IN и следующим за ним OUT. То есть сумму разниц каждой пары IN и OUT в минутах. Для данного примера это будет 360 минут.

Как это можно сделать SQL или PL/SQL скриптом? Нужен пример.

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (галка напротив выбранного ответа).

Comment: Зачем же создавать такие таблицы, простое и, главное, предвидимое обращение к которым требует напряженной работы мозга. Хорошо еще, что Вы не придумали какой-нибудь промежуточной даты. Вот, всласть помучились бы.  
"Не надо на собственную голову обрушивать собственные потребности" А.И. Райкин

Answer (score 1):

По предложению splash58, считаем суммы IN и OUT и получаем их разность (для случаев если IN и OUT гарантированно одинаковое количество:

```
select (sum(decode(event,'OUT',dt-main_dt,NULL))-sum(decode(event,'IN',dt-main_dt,NULL)))*24*60
  from test a,
       (select SYSDATE main_dt from DUAL) b
```

Для перевода дат в минуты считаем их разницу с `SYSDATE`, который получаем подзапросом в `from` что бы он гарантированно не изменился за время выполнения запроса.

Вариант для несбалансированных IN/OUT, для ранних версий Oracle и для исключения любых побочных эффектов:

```
select sum((b.dt-a.dt)*24*60)
  from test a,test b
 where a.event='IN' and b.event='OUT' and b.dt>a.dt
   and not exists(select 1 from test c
                   where c.event='OUT' and c.dt>a.dt and c.dt<b.dt)
```

Способ 2, для версий Oracle >= 9.0, плюс в том, что таблица используется один раз и на ее месте может быть другой запрос собирающий эти данные:

```
select sum((o-i)*24*60)
  from
   (
    select max(decode(event,'IN',dt,NULL)) i,max(decode(event,'OUT',dt,NULL)) o
      from
       (
        select count(1) over (partition by event order by event,dt) as num,event,dt
          from test
       )
     group by num
   )
```

Comment: Если кол-во инов и аутов одинаковое, можно просто посчитать разницу сумм всех таких и таких

Comment: @splash58 А вы знаете эффективный способ в оракле перевести даты в минуты, что бы их просуммировать ?

Comment: @splash58 Спасибо за наводку, проблемы у меня с математикой :) Способ получить минуты придумал.

Comment: я не знаю насчет оракла, но по идее, если это таймштампы, можно просто все посуммировать и повычитать, а потом уж поделить  на 60

Comment: @splash58 В оракле все печальнее, даты сложить ни как нельзя, в принципе. зато получить разницу двух дат (в виде дней с дробной частью) без проблем, чем я и воспользовался